# How do I find the program that I installed?

Tags: software-installation

I installed Google Earth last night and cannot this morning find it. Silly question but why is there not an icon for the program as that method seems nice and simple?

Comment: press the super (windows) key, then type 'ubuntu software', open it and go the **Installed** section.

Answer (score 0):

how did you install it?  via downloaded file or via ppa, etc.?

if you downloaded the file and installed from there it may not have created a .desktop file in /usr/share/applications.

[This page](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-google-earth-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux) may be of help to you.